# PHP output results on to one page

Tags: php, button

i have a system where a user searches for a film and reviews appear on a page with a button next to each review. The button can be selected to look at the individual review but i basically want a button that when selected it will look at all reviews on one page, the code i am using for the individual review is this

```
<?php

ini_set ('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting (E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);


$searchfilm=$_POST['searchfilm'];


//Connect to database



//Filter search
$searchfilm = strtoupper($searchfilm);
$searchfilm = strip_tags($searchfilm);
$searchfilm = trim ($searchfilm);

$query = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT filmreview FROM review WHERE id = '$id'"));
$data = mysql_query("SELECT film.filmname, review.filmreview, review.reviewtitle, review.id FROM film, review WHERE film.filmid = review.filmid AND filmname = '$searchfilm'");  

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{
    // echo $row['filmname'];
    // echo "<b>Film Name:</b> " .$searchfilm;
    echo "<table border=\"2\" align=\"left\">";
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo "<b>Review Title:</b> " .$row['reviewtitle'];
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['filmreview'];
    echo "<p>"; 
    echo "<form method='post' action='analyse1.php'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='reviewid' value='".$row['id']."'>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Analyse'>";
    echo "</form>";     
    echo "</table>";

}

?>
```

Comment: sorry is it that you want one button to view all reviews together?

Comment: That code will show all the records retrieved from the database. Are you just not retrieving everything you want? Show the SQL query, please.

Comment: mine would be.. why would you use `mysql_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc` if you only plan to use the column names?

Comment: i basically want another button which will allow me to select all reviews and put them on another page

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch film reviews since film id inside review table 
you could modify your code above and add another form to get all film reviews
when user click on a button it will redirect him/her to film_reviews.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "getAllReviews"){

    $filmID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['filmid']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM review WHERE filmid = '$filmID'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if(is_resource($res)){
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
           echo "<p>".$row['reviewtitle']."</p>";
           echo "<p>".$row['filmreview']."</p>";
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: this line basically gets the film information 

      $data = mysql_query("SELECT film.filmname, review.filmreview, review.reviewtitle, review.id FROM film, review WHERE film.filmid = review.filmid AND filmname = '$searchfilm'");

Comment: if you want to get all reviews depending on selected movie <br/>
`SELECT * FROM review WHERE filmname = '$searchfilm'`

Comment: i am getting this error for some reason 
( ! ) Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\analyseall.php on line 27

Comment: can you write sorce code? it seems you passed an error varibale to mysql_fetch_assoc or maybe there something wrong in your mysql statement that's why returned boolean instead of resource

Comment: you have a problem here: `$query = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT filmreview FROM review WHERE id = '$id'"));`

$id undefined variable that's why returned empty result

Comment: well the id references the reviews, i was using that for putting a buttton next to individual reviews so not sure if its needed

Comment: if id = review id then there is nothing new here you will only optain one reveiw in return, but since you want to get all reviews depending on film id then replace `$id` with the film id

Comment: the code i have pasted above is what i used to get the reviews listed with a button next to it, i am a bit confused about the use of the id

Comment: would it not need to get both the film id and review id

Comment: no need because if you used film id and review id then your result will be one review, you only need film id and select all reviews from review table

Comment: would you be able to provide an example ? is the code above correct ?

Comment: what is analyze button above want to do?
`echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Analyse'>";`
and beside that does database has review table?, what is the database structure?

Comment: the tables i have are: review - id, reviewtitle, filmreview, filmid then film - filmid, filmname, then positive and negative tables with id, word

Comment: the analyse is for looking at a review individually so i probably dont need it in the above

Comment: you can modify it to send film id to another page, check my answer above

Comment: the problem im having is i have 2 while loops on one page therefore its not recognising the second button

Comment: then change action file for the second form, btw does your site up?

Comment: what do you mean by site up  ?

Comment: ok, then change the action in the form that resposible for individual review with the one i posted above

Comment: but i need both methods, ie do the individual and also all or is that too complicated to do ?

Comment: i am busy with some other work atm will let you know in a few days when i look at it again

Comment: if i add another form then how will the button appear at the top of the other page ?